# Will running a double monitor in clamshell mode put more stress on my computer?

Tags: macbook-pro, closed-clamshell

I'm wondering if my mid-2010 Macbook Pro will be more stressed than it should if I run a 22-inch monitor in clamshell mode.  It seems to be whirring more than usual when I do this, so am I better off just getting an iMac?

Comment: Whirring just means the fans come on to cool it.  I would not worry, unless it gets too hot to touch... Feel the bottom and see.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to answer this objectively, but running it in "clamshell mode" is fine. I've been doing the same for a long time with my MacBook Pro with no issues.

If your external screen is bigger (resolution-wise) than your laptop's native screen, then it will of course need some more graphics power to run, but this is rarely an issue in practice.